# MySQL: Store the result of a COUNT function in variable inside SELECT statement of aggregated query

Tags: mysql

I have a relatively simple database containing three tables, one for `orders`, one for `products` and one for linking orders to different products (`orders_products`). See my query for retrieving a product:

```
SELECT 
    p.product_id,
    p.name,
    @confirmed_nb := COUNT(DISTINCT IF(o.confirmed_on IS NOT NULL AND o.fulfilled_on IS NULL, o.order_id, NULL)) AS confirmed_nb,
    @fulfilled_nb := COUNT(DISTINCT IF(o.fulfilled_on IS NOT NULL, o.order_id, NULL)) AS fulfilled_nb,
    IF(@confirmed_nb > 10, 'POPUPLAR', 'UNPOPULAR') AS popularity,
    @confirmed_nb AS confirmed_nb_from_var
FROM products p
    JOIN orders_products op ON op.product_id = p.product_id
    JOIN orders o ON o.order_id = op.order_id
    GROUP BY p.product_id
```

Orders can have different statuses (like confirmed and fulfilled). One of the things I do in my query when I retrieve details of a `product` is that I count the number of confirmed and fulfilled `orders` that contain the product in question. That part works great.

Now, I would like to use the result of that COUNT function in the SELECT statement to return a value, say a string that describes the popularity of the product.
For that, I use a MySQL variable but I doesn't work. Actually, what I find strange is that, when I run the query, `confirmed_nb` and `confirmed_nb_from_var` are not equivalent, the latter always returning 0.

Any idea what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Execute your code w/o variables in subquery, then process the result using variables in outer query.

Comment: *Actually, what I find strange is that, when I run the query, confirmed_nb and confirmed_nb_from_var are not equivalent, the latter always returning 0.* The query which uses UDVs must have only one source table/subquery and does not contain GROUP BY (including implicit one).

Answer (score 0):

You can plug the `COUNT` subquery directly into the `IF` statement like this:

```
IF(COUNT(DISTINCT IF(o.confirmed_on IS NOT NULL AND o.fulfilled_on IS NULL, o.order_id, NULL)) > 10, 'POPUPLAR', 'UNPOPULAR') AS popularity
```

See [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ab7ee0c7f7fdcc3aaed70b7f0443c7ee).

As for the `confirmed_nb` and `confirmed_nb_from_var` equivalency issue, the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) is clear on this:

> The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is
> undefined. For example, there is no guarantee that SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1
> evaluates @a first and then performs the assignment.
>
> In addition, the default result type of a variable is based on its
> type at the beginning of the statement. This may have unintended
> effects if a variable holds a value of one type at the beginning of a
> statement in which it is also assigned a new value of a different
> type.
>
> To avoid problems with this behavior, either do not assign a value to
> and read the value of the same variable within a single statement, or
> else set the variable to 0, 0.0, or '' to define its type before you
> use it.